# Main differences between P4Merge and DiffMerge

Tags: version-control, mergetool, 3-way-merge

My team is looking for a powerful 3-way merge tool to add to our toolbox. I identified P4Merge and DiffMerge as top candidates for us because they are considered the best here on SO (thank you SO community) and they meet corporate licensing terms.

For the final decision I need a comparison of features of both tools. One difference is that e.g. DiffMerge does not show the common ancestor content in 3-way merge.

**What are the main differentiators between these tools?**

(Please note that this question is explicit about P4Merge and DiffMerge, I know there are other merge tools available as well, but they are not considered here.)

Answer (score 1):

The feature set is quite similar. DiffMerge costs $$$. For this extra cost, you get:

- DiffMerge supports directory comparison, P4Merge does not
- DiffMerge can output diff reports (HTML/text)
- DiffMerge supports both horizontal and vertical split-screen layouts, but P4Merge supports only vertical

There is a [more complete comparison on Wikipedia](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_comparison_tools) of these 2 merge tools (and many others).